# HTML file won't generate anything on webpage using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, linechart

I'm trying to build a basic chart using the Chart.js JavaScript framework. I believe I have everything completely the way it should be given an example I've been following, however it will not generate the chart (or anything) in any browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>ChartJS Analytic</title>
        <script id="src/chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="center"><canvas id="lineChart"></canvas></div>
        <script>
            var lineChartData = {
                labels : ["2010","2011","2012","2013"],
                datasets : [{
                    data : [150,200,250,150]
                }, {
                    data : [200,170,150,200]
                }]
            };

            var lineChart = document.getElementById('lineChart').getContext('2d');
            new Chart(lineChart).Line(lineChartData);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using WebStorm and no errors or warnings are detected. Can anyone tell me what the issue is here?

Comment: have you inserted jquery and `Chart.js` as libraries because I can't see them in your code?

Comment: `chart.js` is in my directory as well as the jquery.

Comment: Is it intentional that you have <script id="src/chart.js"></script> where you link to the js file in an id attribute?

Comment: use `src="src/chart.js"` instead of `id="src/chart.js"`

Comment: Aside from that, you probably must pass the chart type as a string, not as a variable which is `undefined`. `new Chart("lineChart").Line(lineChartData);` Also it doesn't matter what is "in your directory". You need to properly include what you want to use in a page.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I changed `id="src/chart.js"` to `src="src/chart.js"`, and in doing so includes the entirety of Chart.js. Still the same issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in the line with `new Chart(lineChart)...`

This is incorrectly referenced in modern Chart.js. That line should look like this:

```
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(lineChart, {
    data: lineChartData,
    options: lineOptions
});
```